# Get the value of first column of an html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have an HTML table with the following table structure. When I click on the `span` element in the last column I expect to get the value of first `td` in the same row.

```
<tbody>
 <tr >
    <td >1</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>700</td>
    <td >
        <span  onclick="deleterec()" >
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
    <td>76</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td >
        <span onclick="deleterec()" >
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span> 
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
    <td>101</td>
    <td  ">NA</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td >
        <span  onclick="deleterec()" >
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span>
    </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my javascript code , which I used

```
function deleterec(){

  var tr=$(this).closest('tr');
  var x=tr.children('td:first-child').text();
}
```

However, it doesn't return the value of first column. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` in `onclick` function as below, also check how to get first `td` text simply.

```js
function deleterec(obj){
  var tr=$(obj).parents('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
  console.log(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table>
<tbody>
 <tr >
    <td >1</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>700</td>
    <td >
        <span  onclick="deleterec(this)" >
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
    <td>76</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td >
        <span onclick="deleterec(this)" >
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span> 
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
    <td>101</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td >
        <span  onclick="deleterec(this)" >
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span>
    </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also avoid jquery too.

```js
const deleterec = () => {
    let elm = event.target;
  while (elm.tagName !== "TR") {
    elm = elm.parentElement;
  }
  const td = elm.querySelector("td");
  console.log(td.innerText);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>75</td>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>700</td>
      <td>
        <span onclick="deleterec()">
          <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>76</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>600</td>
      <td>
        <span onclick="deleterec()">
          <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>
        <span onclick=" deleterec()">
          <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function deleterec(index) {
        let row = document.querySelectorAll('.tr');
        console.log(row);
        console.log(row[index]);
      }
```

```css
 span {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      i {
        pointer-events: none;
      }
```

```html
  <table>
      <tbody class="table">
        <tr class="tr">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>75</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>700</td>
          <td>
            <span onclick="deleterec(0)">
              <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px"
                >span</i
              >
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>75</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>700</td>
          <td>
            <span onclick="deleterec(1)">
              <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px"
                >span</i
              >
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>75</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>700</td>
          <td>
            <span onclick="deleterec(2)">
              <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-remove fa-stack-1x" style="line-height: 20px"
                >span</i
              >
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

You can pass an index inside a function. or if you create a row dynamically then pass an index.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function deleterec(obj){
  var ab = $(obj).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text()
  console.log(ab);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<table id='ids'>
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>700</td>
    <td>
        <span  onclick="deleterec(this)" >
            <i class="fa fa-remove" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>76</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>
        <span onclick="deleterec(this)" >
            <i class="fa fa-remove" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span> 
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>
        <span  onclick="deleterec(this)" >
            <i class="fa fa-remove" style="line-height: 20px;"></i>
        </span>
    </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: kya hal hai bhai :)